# How do I get access to my client ID and auth? Original developers moved on

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, client

OK, here is my situation.  We had two developers create a Social Networking program for us.  They created a feature that allows it to link to your Facebook account. They said they used a the standard Facebook API and that it uses a token for authorization.  The feature worked great when the code was on our dev site,  dev.maizing.com, but now that it is on www.maizing.com we are having a problem.

I searched and found one PHP file that had several references to dev.maizing.com and I changed them to www.maizing.com  In our app now when I try to link to my Facebook account, I get a long error url.  I noticed it includes ....

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=____________
```

I won't include the whole client_id here.

What I was told is that my original client ID was hardcoded to work with dev and not www.  My original developers are gone and are unreachable.  I think they have the client_id under another account and I don't have access to it.  Have can I get the access to now make our
client_id point to the right server?

Answer (score 1):

Your AppID shown on your app dashboard page is the client_id.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I faced the same issue, I did not know how to get client_id. Only later did I understand that client_id is the AppID. Wayne is asking how to get client_id and I told him that the AppID you see on the page is the client_id itself. Why is it not the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you **need** access to the apps settings, found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[client_id]/summary/

As [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) says, "The URL you specify must be a URL with the same base domain specified in your app's settings..."

So unless you get access to your app settings, you have to stay with "dev.maizing.com"

Sorry.

There is a silver lining though, if you change your app domain to "maizing.com" instead of "dev.maizing.com" then you can us this app from "*.maizing.com" as stated on the tool tip for app domain.